# How to correctly create a Helper or different class for a method that requires instance members?

Tags: c#

We have quite a few services that contain the following `GetSomeValue` method in slight variations, intended for finding a cached value before getting it from the database:

```
public class RandomService
{
    private readonly IJsonDBProvider _db;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;

    public DataService(IJsonDBProvider db,
                       IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        _db = db;
        _context = context;
    }

    public JObject GetSomeValue(string request)
    {
        JObject json;
        string cacheKey = "key";
        string r;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheKey))
        {
            r = _context.HttpContext.Session.GetString(cacheKey);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r))
            {
                r = _db.Execute("ProcedureName", request);
                json = JObject.Parse(r);
                
                if ((string)json["status"] == "ok")
                {
                    _context.HttpContext.Session.SetString(cacheKey, r);
                };
            }
            else
            {
                json = JObject.Parse(r);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            json = JObject.Parse(_db.Execute("ProcedureName", request));
        }

        return json;
    }
}
```

I want to move this method to a separate class, and then just call it from there and pass in `request`, `cacheKey` and `procedureName` as arguments, instead of copy-pasting this code all the time.

The problem is that a static helper class cannot instantiate the `_db` and `_context` services used here. But if I create a non-static class, I have to create an instance each time and pass the services in as arguments, and I am not sure if that is a correct approach in this case.

Is there a way how to instantiate those services in the new class itself? Or is there a different way how to clean up this code?

Comment: Are `db` and `context` being provided by a DI container of some sort? If so, why are you not thinking of also putting the helper in the same container and letting it manage lifetimes, etc?

Comment: Couldn't you pass the db and context to the helper method as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that you have two options. You can create a static class with a static helper method like this:

```
public static class DataHelper
{
    public static JObject GetSomeValue(string request, string cachekey, IJsonDBProvider db, IHttpContextAccessor context)
    { 
     ...
    }
}
```

Or make `DataHelper` an instance like this:

```
public class DataHelper
{
    public DataHelper(IJsonDBProvider db, IHttpContextAccessor context)
    { 
        ...
    }

    public JObject GetSomeValue(string request, string cachekey)
    { 
     ...
    }
}
```

The second option becomes much more useful if you're using Dependency Injection. You can then just request an instance of `DataHelper` in your constructor and DI will wire up `IJsonDBProvider` and `IHttpContextAccessor`